# possible to run/call a function in a batch file directly from cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can I run/call one function which is in a batch file directly from cmd?
I have this test.bat file which contains some function and I want to call/run one of the function without running the whole file. Is it possible?

```
@echo off
:plus
set /p input1=first input:
set /p input2=second input:
set /a n1=input1
set /a n2=input2
set /a ans=%n1%+%n2%
echo %input1%+%input2% = %ans%

REM goto :eof
:sub
set /p input1=first input:
set /p input2=second input:
set /a n1=input1
set /a n2=input2
set /a ans=%n1%-%n2%
echo %input1% - %input2% = %ans%

REM goto :eof
:mul
set /p input1=first input:
set /p input2=second input:
set /a n1=input1
set /a n2=input2
set /a ans=%n1%*%n2%
echo %input1% * %input2% = %ans%
goto :eof
```

Comment: You mean call the labels inside of the script? i.e `:sub`

Comment: Why do you have `goto :eof` commented out? they are essential! Anyway, unfortunately, there is no way to do what you want without modifying your script...

Comment: Do you want to run _part of a Batch file_ without run the Batch file? The answer is obvious... How you know _in which file_ is the (part of) the code you want run?

Comment: Time to accept an answer, please!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want something like this?

(Please note, you could change `call :%~1` to `goto :%~1` if you want to still access labels, sucj as `goto :eof`

```
@echo off

:: This portion will use the paramter sent from cmd window.
call :%~1
goto :eof

:plus
echo Welcome to additions (n+n=n)
set /p input1=first input:
set /p input2=second input:
set /a n1=input1
set /a n2=input2
set /a ans=%n1%+%n2%
echo %input1%+%input2% = %ans%
goto :eof

:sub
echo Welcome to subtractions (n-n=n)
set /p input1=first input:
set /p input2=second input:
set /a n1=input1
set /a n2=input2
set /a ans=%n1%-%n2%
echo %input1% - %input2% = %ans%
goto :eof

:mul
echo Welcome to muptiplications (n*n=n)
set /p input1=first input:
set /p input2=second input:
set /a n1=input1
set /a n2=input2
set /a ans=%n1%*%n2%
echo %input1% * %input2% = %ans%

:eof
pause
```

To then use it, open `cmd` and type (assuming your file is called `mybat.cmd`:

```
mybat.cmd mul
```

Which will in turn in the batch call the label `:mul`

The fact that we use `%~1` instead of `%1` is that it can then also be run as:

```
mybat.cmd "mul"
```

Which will have the exact same result.

Here is a screenshot of this exact script as I tested it.

[image: Extract of commands]

Just as a side note, you could also use `set /p` to prompt user what to run, then simply call the label accordingly. you then just have to run the batch file and not having to run it from cmd each time.

Comment: IMHO this does not answer the question, that specifically say: _"without running the whole file"_...

Comment: @Aacini, it only calls the label inside the file, not the entire file, I suppose it is a matter of translation by the OP. So what OP means in my opinion is: If he runs the file, he needs to go through each label to get to all of them, where this method he can pre-call which label to go to? Sort of the same as running the batch file with a `set /p` or `choice` and then `goto :label`

Comment: You should change `CALL :%~1` to `GOTO :%~1`, then it's possible to access the other arguments int the functions

Comment: @jeb true yes, will add both options.

Answer (score -1):

After the most general way Gerhard mentioned which I would personally simplify it as follows:

```bat
@echo off

if "%1" == "" (echo The file was either run regardless or from cmd without arguments. & exit /b 1)

:: This portion will use the paramter sent from cmd window.
call :%~1
goto :END

:plus
echo Welcome to additions (n+n=n)
set /p "input1=first input: "
set /p "input2=second input: "
set /a "ans=input1+input2"
echo %input1% + %input2% = %ans%

:sub
echo Welcome to subtractions (n-n=n)
set /p "input1=first input: "
set /p "input2=second input: "
set /a "ans=input1-input2""
echo %input1% - %input2% = %ans%

:mul
echo Welcome to muptiplications (n*n=n)
set /p "input1=first input: "
set /p "input2=second input: "
set /a "ans=input1*input2"
echo %input1% * %input2% = %ans%

:END
pause
exit /b 0
```

which I think it is much sorter, there is another way to do that:

- Create a batch file named `additions.bat` which will have the content:

```bat
@call yourfile.bat "plus"
```

- Create a batch file named `subtractions.bat` which will have the content:

```bat
@call yourfile.bat "sub"
```

- Create a batch file named `muptiplications.bat` which will have the content:

```bat
@call yourfile.bat "mul"
```

It will be much easier I think to just double-click the correct batch file and you will have what you want.

Comment: use `if "%1" == ""` instead of `if [%1] == []` . `[]` will not handle arguments with spaced.